# C++, printing a grid: it's too long

Tags: c++, printing, grid

I'm trying to print a grid. I want it to be 50x50, but when I print it's not a square, it's too long!
here is the code:

```
for(int x=0;x<MAP_HEIGHT;x++)
{
for(int y=0;y<MAP_LENGHT;y++)cout<<piano[x][y];
cout<<"\n";
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you printing? Bear in mind that, if you're printing single characters, most fonts are not square. A tall, rectangular font implies that your numerically square grid will be drawn tall and rectangular.

Comment: You didn't show what type `piano` has, nor what values are in there (even if it is an array of `char` embedded `'\t'` could screw the formatting).

Comment: Oh sorry. piano is char, and it prints | if it is on the y axis and _ if it is in the x axis. It prints " " otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Your grid is numerically square, but most fonts are tall and thin. So, despite having the same number of elements in each direction, your grid is drawn taller than it is wide (because each letter is similarly proportioned).

#### Edit

Seeing your name, I thought a nethack reference was in order.

```
-----------
|.........|
|.........|
S.........|
|.........|
|.........|
-----------
```

I cut this room out of the gehennom.des file in the `dat` directory of the nethack source. It's a portion of the Asmodeus level. Note,  that, while the room appears slightly square, it is actually almost twice as wide (9 spaces) as it is tall (5 spaces).

Comment: I see. Anyway to solve that? Any characther that is a square?

Comment: Not really. The closest thing I've seen to fixing it is providing a square font set in e.g. Dwarf Fortress. Unfortunately, DF uses a custom SDL (or is it OpenGL...) interface which can adapt, while your standard terminal emulator will only support non-square fonts.

Comment: Yeah I used that trick when I made a roguelike of mine, but since now I am in a Cartesian coordinate system I'd like to have a mathematical square....

Comment: I'm not aware of any clean way to make this happen in a standard terminal without acquiring (and mandating for all users) a square font.